# Maintaining responsive flex properties when iterating through array using Handlebars

Tags: html, css, handlebars.js

I have the following code (using Handlebars, working code in JSFiddle):

```
  <div class="cards-container">
    {{#each this.cards}}
    <div
      class="card-container container-col-inner col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3"
    >
      <div class="image-card">
        <div class="image-content">
          <p class="title">{{title}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
```

```
{
  "3columnLayout": false,
  "cards": [
    {
      "title": "Card 1"
    },
    {
      "title": "Card 2"
    },
    {
      "title": "Card 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically it iterates through the cards array and creates a `card-container` div for each item. Using bootstrap each div is then assigned a CSS class such as `col-md-6` so that:

- Mobile: items are displayed in single column
- Tablet: items are displayed in 2 column
- Desktop: items are displayed in 3 column

This all worked as expected and visually gave the desired UI (regardless of number of cards): sample below:

[image]

However, as seen in the JSON, I need to have a property that sits outside the individual card level to determine whether or not desktop should break from a 4 column layout to 3.

I don't want to repeat this property for every card within the cards array so have restructured my code as seen in my snippet here (using Handlebars): https://jsfiddle.net/stcfa5wh/20/

However, this now means that whilst I can access the `3columnLayout` value: the HTML is dumped on to the page and I can no longer use `col` in the way I did previously.

For example on tablet I could set each `image-card` to a width of 50%, but it ignores the need for rows.

Can anyone suggest a way to keep both the HTML structure, whilst being able to implement a top level property such as `3columnLayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not understanding why you stopped using Bootstrap when you tried to implement the `3columnLayout` flag. Using Bootstrap, we would use the class `col-lg-4` on each column to create a 3 column layout. So the conditional expression we need on each of our columns is: `{{#if ../3columnLayout}}col-lg-4{{else}}col-lg-3{{/if}}`.

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('Template').innerHTML);

const data = {
  "3columnLayout": true,
  "cards": [{
      "title": "Card 1",
    },
    {
      "title": "Card 2",
    },
    {

      "title": "Card 3",

    },
    {
      "title": "Card 4",

    },
    {
      "title": "Card 5",
    },
    {

      "title": "Card 6",
    },
    {
      "title": "Card 7",
    },
    {
      "title": "Card 8",
    }
  ]
}

const output = template(data);

document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = output;
```

```css
.image-card {
  height: 432px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script id="Template" type="text/template">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {{#each this.cards}}
        <div class="col-md-6 {{#if ../3columnLayout}}col-lg-4{{else}}col-lg-3{{/if}}">
          <div class="image-card">
            <div class="image-content">
              <p class="title">{{title}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
<div id="Output"></div>
```

And here are two fiddles: [one](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/s84k5dtj/) with `3columnLayout` set to `false`; and the [other](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/bjh52mue/) with it set to `true`.

Comment: @cts: Was this helpful to you?

Comment: hey! thanks for your response, I was hoping to achieve this using a property at the row level for example, so that the `3columnLayout` property is not required for each individual card.